# Cross-platform development with git

Tags: git, cross-platform

I'm working on an OpenGL wrapper for C++. Obviously that requires different implementations for different platforms. For example the window management and context creation.

Now the problem is that if I implement a new feature on my primary platform (Windows), the code for the other platforms doesn't include this functionality yet and that seems like a bad idea. I would have to first commit the code for Windows, then the code for Linux, etc.

Is there a different solution for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate branch to work on the feature and merge it to master once it's working on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Even better, additionally write unit tests that ensure that the function is present for all the builds on all the platforms, so that the project will at least build.  Ensure that the test fails if the function is unimplemented (The unit test won't neccessarily be able to fully test the function,but it should be able to at least function as a way to indicate that it's not implemented).